# Getting json data from curl in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, curl, cors

I have a `cUrl` which gives `JSON` data  I  want to use that curl in angularjs but It's giving me **error**

> "Error: $sce:insecurl
>
> Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked"

**Code:**

```
var App = angular.module('App', [  ]);
App.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {  
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'http://125.99.157.180/suez/dispweigh.php',
    ]);
}]);
    

App.controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $sce){
    var url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://125.99.157.180/suez/dispweigh.php');
    $http.get(url)
    .then(function (data) {
         $scope.result = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: Any specific reason you are using curl as the backend is an API you can make an ajax call to get the JSON.

Comment: this curl is form raspberry pi so that's why

Comment: What happens when you use a simple `url` instead of one that has been processed with `$sce`?

Comment: `125.99.157.180/suez/dispweigh.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. Using `$sce` will not bypass a CORS problem.

Comment: Even if it is from raspberry pi you could still make an ajax call right? Also if you are getting CORS issue than you must add allow origin header at server side, with a value from where you are making the call.